# Keyerror when using sessions in flask

Tags: python, session, flask

I have been trying to make a flask app but even though I have declared the session variable, python raises Keyerror when accessing that session variable. the exact traceback is given below too. comment below if you need any more help. I have been getting some warnings about session overflow at times too

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ratan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Ratan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Ratan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Ratan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Ratan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Ratan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Ratan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Ratan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Ratan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Ratan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Ratan\Documents\GitHub\smart-recorder\main.py", line 58, in give_transcript
    transcript = session['text_only_transcript']
  File "C:\Users\Ratan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 377, in <lambda>
    __getitem__ = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i]
  File "C:\Users\Ratan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\sessions.py", line 84, in __getitem__
    return super(SecureCookieSession, self).__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'text_only_transcript'
```

Here is the code

```py
import other_functions
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import redirect
from flask import url_for
from flask import session
## Imports ##

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = other_functions.get_secret_key()

## app config  ##

# functions


@app.route('/home/')
@app.route('/')
def main_page():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/from-yt-link', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def youtube_link_page():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('give_link_page.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        video_url = request.form['url-enter']
        video_id = other_functions.get_video_id(video_url)
        session['video_id'] = video_id
        return redirect(url_for('give_transcript'))


@app.route('/upload_page/')
@app.route('/upload/')
def upload():
    return render_template('upload_page.html')

'''
The error originates here in the get_transcript() function
'''
@app.route('/get-transcript/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@app.route('/transcript/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def give_transcript():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            transcript = other_functions.return_transcript(session["video_id"])
            session['transcript'] = transcript
            text_only_transcript = ''
            for i in transcript:
                text_only_transcript = text_only_transcript + i['text'] + ' '
            session['text_only_transcript'] = text_only_transcript
            return render_template('transcript.html', transcript=transcript, raw_text=text_only_transcript)
        except KeyError:
            return '<p>No YT Url Provided</p>'
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        search_query = request.form['search-query']
        print(f"we obtained {search_query} form js with ajax")
        transcript = session['text_only_transcript']
        list_of_words = transcript.split(' ')
        where_is_the_word_present = other_functions.a_small_engine_for_finding_words(
            transcript,  search_query)
        print(f'the word is present in places {where_is_the_word_present}')
        if where_is_the_word_present != []:
            for i in where_is_the_word_present:
                list_of_words.insert(i, '<mark>')
                list_of_words.insert(i+2, '</mark>')
            print(list_of_words)
        else:
            print('lol, word not found')
        return '', 204


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Thanks in advance for answering my question :)

**EDIT**: Solved it, check comments on the accepted answer below

Comment: Are you sure that you sure that you have called get endpoint before calling post?

Comment: The error. message sure looks like it's unhappy with `session['text_only_transcript`]`.  Are you positive the session has such a field?  You might try `session.get('text_only_transcript', <some default value>)` so your program won't fail if this field is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `text_only_transcript` to the session in the GET method.

And you got this error in POST method.

Here is some of the possible reason.

1. `text_only_transcript` key is not added in the session, because you forgot to call the URL via GET method. So you have to call the URL first with GET method, then with the POST method.
2. Probably the session got deleted. Please verify your session whether you have all the key or not.

Comment: I did try this methord but this raised another error werkzeug.routing.BuildError

werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'give_transcript' with values ['raw_transcript']. Did you forget to specify values ['raw_trascript']?

Comment: i think the error is in this function redirect(url_for('give_transcript')). it can't able to build endpoint for this. did you add any parameter for `give_transcript` function?

Comment: I finally found out what was the problem, as my session data was too large (above 4KB), my browser would omit this data and hence I got a keyerror when accesing that data. So, I switched from client-side sessions to server side sessions and it works like a charm now